# Bulk delete records from DynamoDB of any scale, paginated delete vs fetch all then delete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have a requirement to delete a large number of records from DDB.

On a high level I see there are two options after fetching records from DDB using pagination ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html)).

1. Delete records after receiving each response.
2. Fetch all records and then delete in batches.

On 1, I am concerned there might be inconsistencies in record fetching if DDB is altered on the fly. Want to understand if there is any other reasoning to prefer 1?

Comment: Also be aware of the option of [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html). Probably not what you want in this particular case, but just want to make sure you're aware of it, perhaps for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is probably option 2, so long as you shuffle your results before issuing the delete requests. DynamoDB Scan will return results per-partition in order, and you would most likely get a hot-key if you tried to delete them in the order you retrieved them.

Read all the items, shuffle them and BatchWrite(delete).